# The installed "SQLite browser" icon in Ubuntu not shown correctly, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: icons

I installed SQLite browser in Ubuntu, however, the icon shown is the 'gear' as indicated below. I checked it in the 'Ubuntu software', it seems that I launched SQLite browser successfully and the icon is shown correctly. Hence I am seeking assistance to solve the icon problem.

[image]

Thanks for everyone's reply.

1. Hi @FedKad , I found the `.desktop` files after running the code you provided. However, when I executed the file, it shows `No such file or directory` as below. I am not sure if I opened these files correctly.

```
(base) ch@VirtualBox:~$ find / -name *.desktop 2>/dev/null -exec grep -l 'DB Browser for SQLite' '{}' \;
/snap/sqlitebrowser/3233/meta/gui/sqlitebrowser.desktop
/snap/sqlitebrowser/3233/share/applications/sqlitebrowser.desktop
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/sqlitebrowser_sqlitebrowser.desktop
(base) ch@VirtualBox:~$ exec/snap/sqlitebrowser/3233/meta/gui/sqlitebrowser.desktop
bash: exec/snap/sqlitebrowser/3233/meta/gui/sqlitebrowser.desktop: No such file or directory
(base) ch@VirtualBox:~$ exec/snap/sqlitebrowser/3233/share/applications/sqlitebrowser.desktop
bash: exec/snap/sqlitebrowser/3233/share/applications/sqlitebrowser.desktop: No such file or directory
(base) ch@CH-VirtualBox:~$ exec/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/sqlitebrowser_sqlitebrowser.desktop
bash: exec/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/sqlitebrowser_sqlitebrowser.desktop: No such file or directory
```

Thanks in advance if you could correct me or guide me on this issue.

2. Hi @vanadium , yes you are correct that I installed this software via snap and the reason is that when I installed this app via APT, it shows the problem below, so I could only change to install it via snap.

```
No apt package "sqlitebrowser", but there is a snap with that name.
Try "snap install sqlitebrowser"

E: Unable to locate package sqlitebrowser
```

Is there any one knowing that why I cannot install SQLite browser via APT? How I can do it? Thanks!

Comment: It may help if you [edit] your question and add the contents of the related `.desktop` file. To locate that file, use the command `find / -name *.desktop 2>/dev/null -exec grep -l 'DB Browser for SQLite' '{}' \;`

Comment: When installed via APT, an icon is properly installed. Your installation may be snap: check whether it appears in the output of `snap list`, and thus be a snap packaging problem. IF needed, you can install an icon manually, but first provide the info FedKad requested.